# Managing the "Managed Metadata Service" on multiple environment

Tags: managed-metadata, administration, term-store

I Have added a Managed metadata service to my web application, and then I added a term store hierarchy inside my staging server. And I link the “Wiki Category” site Column , inside my enterprise Wiki site collection with the managed metadata. After that  I backup the site collection from the staging env , and I restore it insde my production server. But doing so will not move the Managed metadata service and the term store hireachy.

So my question is how I can backup and restore the managed metadata service and its term store hireachy from my staging to my production server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup and restore the Managed Metadata database as well. Make sure to restore the database with the same name as the existing Managed metadata database to overwrite it.

Here is a nice guide: http://sharepointtrac.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/backup-and-restore-managed-metadata-term-stores-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: but how is this done, i mean on CA there is an option to backup a site collection but there is not any option to backup/restore service applications ?

Comment: Easiest way is to do it in SQL Management Studio

Comment: Updated with a link

Answer (score 0):

You can use following powershell scripts to export mms from source farm as `.cab` file  and then import this cab file at the destination farm.
The script:

```
$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "\\server\share\mmsdata.cab"


$mmsApplication = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}
$mmsProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Service Connection"}
Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData $mmsApplication.Id -ServiceProxy $mmsProxy -Path "\\server\share\mmsdata.cab" -OverwriteExisting
```